# c# object doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, constructor

**Disclaimer** : *I'm new to C#*.  I'm most likely doing something really wrong but I have no clue **what** to try to **Google** etc so I hope someone can tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Anyway, I'm creating a player object with my constructor in `createPlayer` method, and I can print the values of the created object, however afterwards I can't print it anymore, it says:

> player1 doesn't exist in the current context.

What should I do?

### main file

```
using System;

namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                createPlayer();

            Console.WriteLine(player1.Name); //Doesn't exist in current context
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static public void createPlayer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nType in your name :");
            Player player1 = new Player(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.WriteLine("\n Name: " + player1.Name + "\n Speed: " + player1.Speed + "\n Defence: " + player1.Defence + "\n Damage: " + player1.Damage);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to continue, Press 2 to reroll.");
        }
    }
}
```

### Constructor

```
 using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace projekti
{
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Speed;
        public int Damage;
        public int Defence;
        public int Health;
        public Player(string nm)
        {
            Name = nm;
            Random r = new Random();
            Speed = r.Next(1, 26);
            Damage = r.Next(1, 26);
            Defence = r.Next(1, 26);
            Health = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`player1` instantiated in `createPlayer()` and therefore is scoped locally to that function. If you want to give other functions access to it, you can make `createPlayer()` return `player1`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var player1 = createPlayer();

    Console.WriteLine(player1.Name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
static public Player createPlayer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nType in your name :");
    Player player1 = new Player(Console.ReadLine()); 
    Console.WriteLine("\n Name: " + player1.Name + "\n Speed: " + player1.Speed + "\n Defence: " + player1.Defence + "\n Damage: " + player1.Damage);
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to continue, Press 2 to reroll.");

    return player1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought it was something like this but didn't really have a clue on how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you create the object of ***Player***  inside ***createPlayer()***  method so the scope of the obejct of ***Player*** will be limitted to that block only. so you cant use it out side of this method.

ok so you can do like

*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var player1 =   createPlayer();
            Console.WriteLine(player1.Name); //Doesn't exist in current context
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static public Player createPlayer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nType in your name :");
            Player player1 = new Player(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.WriteLine("\n Name: " + player1.Name + "\n Speed: " + player1.Speed + "\n Defence: " + player1.Defence + "\n Damage: " + player1.Damage);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress 1 to continue, Press 2 to reroll."); return player1;
        }
```

*

so your createPlayer method will return the current object which you created and you will be able to use it inside main.

Comment: Whilst true, it's not the end of the world.  Perhaps there is a way to fix the problem as the others have done?  Otherwise, you are just _diagnosing_ and not proving a _solution_.  Wishing you well

Comment: yes, but as per the coding its looks like beginner  , so at this stage we must give the suitable answer that can be understandable by the questioner

Comment: You're missing the point and also a chance to get an upvote.  It's nice to get an explanation of what is wrong (as you have done), though it is better to show **how to fix it**

Answer (score -1):

The *Garbage Collector* (GC) will dispose `player1` in the end of scope **}** so in `Console.WriteLine(player1.Name);` the object `player1` is **not** alive.

You need to create a `public` properties for your `Player` instance . You can follow this Code to solve your issue.

```
namespace project
{
 class Program
 {
    public static Player player1{get;set;}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        createPlayer();
        Console.WriteLine(player1.Name); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void createPlayer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nType in your name :");
        player1 = new Player(Console.ReadLine());
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not true that `player1` is _"disposed"_.  It is marked as subject to GC sure.  There is no explicit call to `Dispose()` nor is there a `using () { }` however for it to be subject to immediate disposal.

Comment: `createPlayer()` and `Main()` are static and therefore cannot access the non-static member `Player1`. Also, the name of the property shouldn't be capitalised.